# Python subprocess throws [Errno 2] No such file or directory, error generated only when it on a remote host

Tags: python, linux, ssh, subprocess, python-2.6

I'm running python 2.6. I'm getting the subprocess throws [Errno 2] No such file or directory only when I run the script via ssh.

For example, if I run the script manually on the machine, there are no errors, but if I do ssh hostname `script.py --host hostname` it generates the error and tells me that File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py is missing, but that's not true as both servers have that file.

I've written the subprocess call like this:

```
p4 = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

The command just contains a list.

Any ideas why it works locally, but not remotely?

Comment: Will you please give full traceback? If you can give code in `script.py` then it will be helpful

Comment: turns out that the problem was how I was calling the command. I wasn't providing the absolute path. The command is located in /sbin and since that wasn't in my PATH it wasn't executing and kept generating this error.

Comment: You can give answer to your same answer, other will get help from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this was to simply have the command set to the absolute path, for example, instead of mke2fs, I needed /sbin/mke2fs.

Comment: if there are several commands, you could pass `PATH` envvar instead: `env=dict(os.environ, PATH=os.environ.get('PATH', os.defpath)+":/sbin")`, to avoid changing all commands if `PATH` changes.